# Awaiting async method for fixed interval

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task-parallel-library

I want to await an async method for fixed interval. If that interval is passed I want to show loading icon to the user and keep waiting for the async method.
Once the response is available, I want to hide the loading icon and show the result.
What are ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a timer. Assuming your are using WPF:

```
public async Task DoStuff()
{
    DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, seconds);
    timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
    timer.Start();

    await YourTask();
    timer.Stop();
    this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;            
}

private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Cursor = Cursors.Wait;
}
```

So your timer should be started. While YourTask runs the timer fires and should change the cursor to the wait cursor. Needs some improvements from you.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways to achieve this. From the top of my head:

- You could start a timer that shows the busy indicator after a fixed time immediately before calling your method, and when the method completes stop the timer and/or hide the busy indicator.
- You could store the task from the method in a variable, await both that and a fixed interval task (`Task.Delay(...)`) using `Task.WhenAny(...)`, then check whether the actual work is complete and if not hard-await the work task after showing the busy indicator.

Which one of those (if any) would be the best approach depends on your used UI framework and other requirements.

Also: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Answer (score 0):

That's not hard to do.

```
Task t = your task to wait;
Task timeout = Task.Delay(1000);
Task finished = await Task.WhenAny(timeout, t);

if (finished == timeout)
{
    ShowLoadingIcon();
}

await t;
```